# Reading txt file into a tuple

Tags: c#, loops, text, tuples

If my txt file contained similar rows to these:

```
1.1, 0.1836856, 5.6
3.3, -5.5, 43.44
-0.38162, 6.636666E-08, 3.1
1.01516E-07, 0.3695395, 1.5
```

How can read the file into a Tuple ?

```cs
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\MyFile.txt"));

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    var val1 = decimal.Parse(values[0], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
    var val2 = decimal.Parse(values[1], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
    var val3 = values[2];

    Tuple<decimal, decimal, string> myTuple = Tuple.Create<decimal, decimal, string>(val1, val2, val3);
}
```

Comment: Off Topic, but you should dispose of your reader after the loop ends. Consider using the `using` keyword

Comment: I'd get rid of the spaces in your text file or trim your string values. Currently val3 = " 5.6".

Comment: @GrantWinney True, but he isn't parsing val3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're basically there.. just add each Tuple to a List so they're not lost when each iteration ends.

Define a List, outside of and before the `while` loop:

```
var results = new List<Tuple<decimal, decimal, string>>();
```

Then add each new Tuple instance inside the loop:

```
results.Add(Tuple.Create(val1, val2, val3));
```

You might also consider replacing `File.OpenRead()` with [`File.ReadLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It opens your file, reads all the lines in, and closes it, in one go.

---

Here's something that looks really different than what you have... just throwing it out there. Whether or not it's clearer is up to you. It uses LINQ.

It reads the file, then splits and creates a `Tuple` for each line, generating the same List.

```
var results = (from line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
               let values = line.Split(',')
               select Tuple.Create(decimal.Parse(values[0], NumberStyles.Float),
                                   decimal.Parse(values[1], NumberStyles.Float),
                                   values[2])).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help & the examples.